# Client socket cannot connect but does not throw an SocketException

Tags: c#, sockets

My asynchronous connect code is very rudimentary and is as followed:

```
private Socket _socket;
public void Connect(IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint, bool persistentConnection)
{
    _logger.Trace("Attempting To Connect To " + remoteEndPoint.Address);
    _remoteEndPoint = remoteEndPoint;
    _persistentConnection = persistentConnection;

    _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
                         SocketType.Stream, 
                         ProtocolType.Tcp);

    _socket.BeginConnect(_remoteEndPoint, ConnectCallback, null);
}
```

The `Connect()` method is accompanied by `ConnectCallback()` which is the where the problem I will describe shortly occurs:

```
private void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    try
    {
        _socket.EndConnect(asyncResult);
        _logger.Trace("Successfully Connected To " + _remoteEndPoint.Address);
    }
    catch (SocketException)
    {
        _logger.Trace("Failed To Connect To " + _remoteEndPoint.Address);
        if (_persistentConnection)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
            Connect(_remoteEndPoint, true);
            return;
        }
    }

    _socketWriter.AssignSocket(_socket);
    _socket.BeginReceive(..);
}
```

My networking code is encapsulated within a single assembly. Today I decided to reference the assembly from another applications and found the `ConnectCallback` method to behave very oddly.

I make a call to `Connect()` when the *server application is not running*. This means it is not physically possible for the connection to succeed. Because the remote end point is not available, I would expect `EndConnect` to throw an exception. Instead `EndConnect` appears to succeed because even though the socket is not really connected, my code proceeds to make a call to `_socket.BeginReceive` which of course, throws an exception because the socket is not connected.

What is especially bizarre is that if I place a break point on the opening `try` brace  and step-through the call back code the exception is thrown and handled.

This happens on local host.

Why am I experiencing this behaviour and how can I ensure that `EndConnect` throws a `SocketException` is the connection cannot established consistently?

Comment: please put together a full, runnable example that demonstrates the behavior -- also try changing the port just to make sure you're not really running a server when you don't think you are.  Obviously the c# methods aren't broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only return from the `catch` if `_persistentConnection` is true. If not, you call `BeginReceive()` anyway.